# Merging make and cmake's make into build system

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake

I have to merge cmake's makes and makes in our build systems. The build systems are supposed to be able to work with both options make and cmake. The problem is that cmake's make exports do not contain all variables and settings, which need to be set as make in our build systems. Basically, we use three complicated build systems for cross platform development and I do not like setting everything on many places, because then it is hard to maintain the system like that.
E g. makefiles from many coders in all build system contains include common file like:

```
include $(PROJECT_CONF_DIR)/common/something.mk
```

How to solute it by cmake? I do not like modifying coders' CMakeLists.txt (max. one row solution for them) and I also do not like modifying cmake exports into make files.
Basically, I need to put somewhere in cmake command or cmake's export (the best) some link which will lead to include all 'garbage' expecting by our build tool chains.
Make sure that CMakeLists.txt can contain many cmake subprojects and libraries.

e.g. Our build system from makefiles contains something like:

```
directories-default:
    mkdir -p $(BUILD_DIR)
    mkdir -p $(OBJ_DIR)
```

I need to implement it somehow in cmake include.

Comment: Depending on the kind of things that need to be shared, in CMake you have `include` and `add_subdirectory`. Does that not work for you?

Comment: In CMake usually the build directory is the one from which the cmake command is invoke (e.g. you do `mkdir -p build; cmake ..` possibly in a script like build.sh). If you want to have a separate directory for the executables (which I assume is what BUILD_DIR is) you can have a look at the `CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` variable. If you need to create a file in CMake you can use `file(MAKE_DIRECTORY "dir_name")`. You can put your common logic in a CMake function in a file that you `include`

Comment: How to create cmake switch in makefiles for calls like: make directories-default

Answer (score 0):

To be able to run `make directories-default` after configuration, you have to [create a target](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_target.html). You can make a target that will call a custom command, which would run the shell commands you need.

```
add_custom_target(directories-default COMMAND mkdir -p "dir1" COMMAND mkdir -p "dir2")
```

The syntax above will result in a target that is always considered out of date, ie every time you run `make directories-default` (or `make all`), the commands will be executed. If you don't want to re-run the command every time you can use a [custom command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html):

```
add_custom_command(OUTPUT "dir3" "dir4" COMMAND mkdir -p "dir3" COMMAND mkdir -p "dir4")
add_custom_target(directories-default2 DEPENDS "dir3" "dir4")
```

Here `make directories-default2` will only run the commands the first time you run it. You can also create a dependency chain of commands using the DEPENDS argument in `add_custom_command`.